# How to optimize this formula in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a line of code in my app that I've identified as a bottleneck:

```
Byte rSource, rSource1, rSource2, rSource3, rSource4;
Float32 mult1, mult2, mult3, mult4;

// this gets called many many times inside a loop:
rSource = (int)(rSource1 * mult1 + rSource2 * mult2 + rSource3 * mult3 
    + rSource4 * mult4);
```

Is there any way to speed up how long this call takes? I've seen some posts about inline assembly code which I'm guessing might be a way to do this faster, but I have no idea how to go about using inline assembly or what exact assembly instructions I would need in order to perform this calculation.

Interestingly, if I change the line to this:

```
rSource = (Byte)(rSource1 * mult1 + rSource2 * mult2 + rSource3 * mult3 
    + rSource4 * mult4);
```

the calculation takes almost twice as long (I'm guessing this is because the compiler adds checks to ensure that the value being cast to `Byte` is actually between 0 and 255 whereas with the `int` cast it doesn't do any checking).

I can add an asm method to my code like so which does a saturation or something (online code, just an example):

```
int a, y;
__asm__("usat %0, #8, %1\n\t" : "=r"(y) : "r"(a));
```

How would I write something like this to handle my method above?

Comment: Questions like this are better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @rmaddy: thanks, but why exactly? A helpful thing for the FAQ there would be "why ask a question here instead of on stack overflow?"

Comment: You have working code you are looking to improve. That's a code review. This site is for getting help with code that doesn't work. At least that's my overly simplified take. There's a good meta post about this (and using programmers SE). I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: This question would probably only be a good fit for Code Review if the context code were also provided. It's possible that this has been misidentified as a bottleneck through misanalyzing.

Comment: @maddy you mean [this one?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7182/what-goes-on-programmers-se-a-guide-for-stack-overflow)

Comment: @rmaddy I believe you are looking for **[this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/255171)**.

Comment: @nhgrif: why would you say that specifically? It's also possible that this has *not* been misidentified as a bottleneck.

Comment: This one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in and this one: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266341/what-are-the-differences-between-stack-overflow-programmers-and-code-review?lq=1

Comment: This question isn't off-topic here.

Comment: This question is on topic here, especially since he only wants to know about the performance of one line of code and not about other parts of his code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Agreed. It is legitimate to ask for optimization techniques on specific classes of problem (this question would be better if it included a little more context about how this line fits into the overall goal of the function).

Comment: It is possible that it hasn't been misidentified, but without the same context, it's impossible for anyone else to run the code and check for themselves. Moreover the optimization might be simply in doing your loop differently or something, but that can't be recommended without any context.

Answer (score 3):

If this line of code is your bottleneck, the it is certainly in an inner loop. I have to assume that either the `Rsource` values or `mult` values are being changed during the loop (seeing the loop would be helpful).

(Side note: variables should always begin with a lowercase letter; `Rsource` looks like a type name.)

Assuming this is in some for-loop, you almost certainly want to replace it with the [Accelerate framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/). We'd have to see more of the algorithm to know what function you're really implementing, but the Accelerate framework is designed for combining large tables of numbers.

Comment: Yes, the source and mult values are being changed during the loop. If they weren't being changed inside the loop, there wouldn't be much reason to make this calculation inside the loop. There's more to the method than what's here, but it's basically doing a linear interpolation of four source pixels.

Comment: See `vImageInterpolatedLookupTable_PlanarF` (which might do exactly what you want) or `vDSP_vsma` (which you can probably build what you want out of). Generally, however, you have to design your data structures and algorithm around Accelerate. You don't optimize at the level of a single line of code.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any sort of "getting started with Accelerate" links? I've made a few attempts at understanding Accelerate in order to use the DSP functionality, but my mental processes and Apple documentation don't mesh very well - with the Accelerate documentation, I've never been able to get from the docs to actual working code.

Comment: I recommend starting at "Getting Started with Mathematical Computation" (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_Math/_index.html). Also WWDC 2013 Session 713 (The Accelerate Framework) https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/ and WWDC 2014 Session 703 (What's New in the Accelerate Framework).

Comment: To use Accelerate, you must rework how you think about your algorithm. There are generally no loops in code that calls Accelerate. You have a setup stage where you organize your data the way Accelerate wants it (or better, you just keep your data stored in that format all the time). Then you call a series of Accelerate functions to transform all the data. And then you unpack the result (if necessary) back into more convenient data structures. For a real-life example with comments, see https://github.com/rnapier/richtext-coretext/blob/master/PinchText/Classes/PinchTextLayer.m

Comment: I highly recommend spending some time trying to "get" `adjustViewPositions:count:forTouchPoint:` in the above link, and as an easier first-step, understanding `addPoint:toPositions:count:`.